# Get the day from date string

Tags: javascript, date

how to get the day from date string in JavaScript?

```
Output:
2015-06-25 - Thursday
2015-07-10 - Friday
```

Comment: Do you mean that it's a string? If so, why not: `"2015-06-25".split("-")[2]`

Comment: Do you mean new Date("2015-06-25").getDay()?

Comment: yes the day with that date and yes its a string.

Comment: and the output shoud be like "monday, tuesday etc.."

Comment: You could use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var d = new Date("2015-06-25");
var weekday = [];
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var day = weekday[d.getDay()]; // Wednesday
```

Comment: great! :) work like charms

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateParts = "2015-06-25".split('-');
(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"])[new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2], 0, 0, 0).getDay() - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var daysOfTheWeek = ['Sun','Mon','Tues','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
var date = new Date("2015-06-25");
var day = daysOfTheWeek[ date.getDay() ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`getDay()` - method returns the day of the week expressed as an integer from `0` (`Sunday`) to `6` (`Saturday`).

```
function getWeekDay(dateString){
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var weekdays = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
                     ^                                       ^                   ^
               index 0                                       4                   6

    return weekdays[date.getDay()];
}        
getWeekDay("2015-06-25"); // calling getWeekDay method
// return day: Thursday
```